# Javascript - finding an object's container

Tags: javascript

If I create an object

```
var O = { A : {}, B : {}}
```

I then set

```
O.A.foo = function() { }
O.B.foo = function() { }
```

How can `foo()` find out whether its parent is `A` or `B`?

Comment: If you're going to be doing that, it might be better to `prototype`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) is the key:

```
O.A.foo = O.B.foo = function() {
    if (this === O.A) {
        // it's A
    }
    else if (this === O.B) {
        // it's B
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/2nhnH/

---

This does seem like a bit of a code smell, however.

Comment: Ah perfect thanks - I assumed this would refer to the function itself but that makes total sense. It does stink but it was just a contrived example, I won't be replicating that pattern in real code.

Comment: +1 - It only really makes sense if you're passing the function an object and want to see if the parameter is an ancestor of the function.  I still think `prototype` should be used, but I guess it still depends on the implementation.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe there's more to your question, because the answer is that the functions already know, since they are separate functions.

```
O.A.foo = function() { /* this is called on A */ }
O.B.foo = function() { /* this is called on B */ }
```

Comment: Very good point. Also, I have your book on my Amazon wishlist! `*wave*`

Comment: But what if there a random container of objects, and he's calling that generic function (like `printInfo`), which is dependent on the type of object it is?  I don't know, I see many ways to handle that situation, so I'm still trying to understand the purpose myself.

Comment: @vol7ron That's a different question. The question here was unrelated to the *type* of the object. The OP wanted to know which object it was.

Comment: Thanks for your time guys - there actually isn't any use for the example. I was just interested in how you might reference the parent of a function if you wanted to, which Matt already answered, the example was just an easy way to ask.

Comment: @RaymondChen: No it is, but you're using *type* to mean *datatype* where I mean it to be a difference in user defined objects (e.g. `O.A`,`O.B`).  If you are randomly selecting objects, each of which have the same named prototyped method, then you don't necessarily know the ancestry.

Comment: You know because you attached the method to only one object, so it can be invoked only on that object.